# Automated exports of Current Data Storage Usage data

Tags: data-storage, storage-limit

Is there a way to access the storage data rendered in Current Data Storage Usage (Data Management -> Storage Usage) such that automated reports can be created to track storage by object?

I can envision a job that performs object counts and calculates storage, but I'm wondering if there's an existing utility (built-in or third-party) that already does this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit REST api that shows File and DataStorage of the org.You can build a service in apex or any other system connecting to salesforce to send notifications .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is useful. Is there any way to get at storage by object?

Comment: No there is no api per object